# Pytorch image segmentation transfer learning

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, transfer-learning

I am new in Pytorch. My question is: How do I apply transfer learning to a custom dataset? I am doing image segmentation on brain tumors. I can find examples which use U-net structure but I could not find examples using weights of the pre-trained models for a U-net image segmentation?

Comment: You can use load_state_dict function to initialize your model with pretrained model’s weight’s.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain pre-trained models in two ways:

1. Model weights or complete models shared in formats such `.pt` or `.pth`:
   In this case, [Saving and Loading Models](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) is a good starting point. Copying from the tutorial there, you could load a model as

```py
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

2. The other way is to load the model from torchvision. A list is available models is available at [Torchvision Models](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html). U-Net is not available yet. However, it is possible to load a pre-trained model as the encoder and write a separate decoder to form a U-Net with a pre-trained encoder.
   In this case, the model object returned from the function calls shown in the API are already loaded with pretrained weights when `pretrained=True`.

For writing a custom dataloader, [PyTorch data loaders](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) may be a useful guide.